# Is there a reliable way to detect POSIXlt objects representing a time which does not exist due to DST?

Tags: r, datetime, dst

I have the following problem: the date column in data I get contains dates that do not exist due to daylight saving time. (For example 2015-03-29 02:00 does not exist in Central European Time, because the clock gets set directly from 01:59 to 03:00 because DST takes effect on this day)

Is there an easy and reliable way to determine if a date is valid with respect to daylight saving time?

This is not trivial because of the properties of the datetime classes.

```
# generating the invalid time as POSIXlt object
test <- strptime("2015-03-29 02:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="CET")

# the object seems to represent something at least partially reasonable, notice the missing timezone specification though
test
# [1] "2015-03-29 02:00:00"

# strangely enough this object is regarded as NA by is.na
is.na(test)
# [1] TRUE

# which is no surprise if you consider:
is.na.POSIXlt
# function (x) 
# is.na(as.POSIXct(x))

as.POSIXct(test)
# [1] NA

# inspecting the interior of my POSIXlt object:
unlist(test)
# sec    min   hour   mday    mon   year   wday   yday  isdst   zone gmtoff
# "0"    "0"    "2"   "29"    "2"  "115"    "0"   "87"   "-1"     ""     NA
```

So the simplest way I thought of is to check the `isdst` field of the `POSIXlt` object, the help for `POSIXt` describes the filed as follows:

> isdst
>   Daylight Saving Time flag. Positive if in force, zero if not,
>   negative if unknown.

Is checking the `isdst` field save in the sense that this field is only `-1` if the date is invalid due to dst-changes or can it be `-1` for some other reasons?

Info on version, platform and locale

```
R.version
# _                           
# platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
# arch           x86_64                      
# os             mingw32                     
# system         x86_64, mingw32             
# status                                     
# major          3                           
# minor          3.1                         
# year           2016                        
# month          06                          
# day            21                          
# svn rev        70800                       
# language       R                           
# version.string R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
# nickname       Bug in Your Hair            
Sys.getlocale()
# [1] "LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your example. When I execute your code, I do not get `is.na(test) FALSE`, but `TRUE` and I get the timezone CEST when executing `test`. 
Two possibilities: (1) Sys.getlocale(), (2) What R version do you use?

Comment: `is.na(test)` should be `TRUE`  
I'm using `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")` `"German_Austria.1252"` but the example turns out the same if I do `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "german")` as well as `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "english")` the timezone setting in strptime should take care of choosing the correct timezone.  
R-version is: R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)  
running on: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64bit Windows 7)

Comment: Guess it's OS dependent and I also cannot reproduce your example. What happens if you try `as.POSIXct(test)`? I'm on Linux and I noticed that `POSIXlt` objects sometimes represent invalid times, while `POSIXct` don't. If I try `as.POSIXct(test)` I get `2015-03-29 01:00:00 CET`, i.e. datetime is corrected. Maybe you can obtain your check trying `identical(as.POSIXlt(as.POSIXct(test)),test)`.

Comment: Ah sorry for my first post. I have `is.na(test)  FALSE`, and not TRUE as in your example.
BTW: There is a new package called `anytime`, which converts "any" time format. You can try this (after downloading it), for me it works:
`anytime::anytime(test)`[1] "2015-03-29 01:00:00 CET"

Comment: anytime does almost what i want. anytime converts 02:01 the date to 01:01 CET but i'm quite certain that the timestamps in my dataset correspond to 03:01 CEST. Also the main issue is actually not converting the times but finding the invalid ones.

Comment: I would check the entries against the TZ, if there's none, you can't know if it is in dst or not, some dates can be unlcear about DST status at this time, so better focus on incomplete POSIXlt object (no zone) than on the isdst field IMHO.

Comment: I also get `is.na(test) == TRUE` on R 3.2.2, Windows x64. What is the problem again?

Comment: The problem is that an object that seems not to be `NA` (because it gets printed as `"2015-03-29 02:00:00"` is `NA` according to `is.na`.

Comment: _By definition_, you test that an object is `NA` with `is.na`.

Comment: So the `NA` value is not unique in `POSIXlt`? (consider `identical(test, as.POSIXlt(NA))`)

Comment: The underlying bit-representation of `NA` (which is what `identical` tests) is beside the point. Its semantic meaning is defined according to how functions like `is.na` and comparison operators behave.

Comment: For example `NaN`s can have different bit-representations too, and the help file for `NaN` says not to use `identical` on them.

Comment: I would say you should use `test[["isdst"]] == -1` to find invalid DST ones. According to the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html), `isdst` is pretty good at guessing for most dates whether they are valid or not, but it is platform independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `as.POSIXct(test)` seems to be platform dependent, adding a layer of complexity to getting a *reliable* method.  On my windows machine, (R 3.3.1), `as.POSIXct(test)` produces `NA`, as also reported by OP. However, on my Linux platform (same R version), I get the following:

```
times = c ("2015-03-29 01:00",
           "2015-03-29 02:00",
           "2015-03-29 03:00")

test <- strptime(times, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="CET")

test
#[1] "2015-03-29 01:00:00 CET"  "2015-03-29 02:00:00 CEST" "2015-03-29 03:00:00 CEST"
as.POSIXct(test)
#[1] "2015-03-29 01:00:00 CET"  "2015-03-29 01:00:00 CET"  "2015-03-29 03:00:00 CEST"
as.character(test)
#[1] "2015-03-29 01:00:00" "2015-03-29 02:00:00" "2015-03-29 03:00:00"
as.character(as.POSIXct(test))
#[1] "2015-03-29 01:00:00" "2015-03-29 01:00:00" "2015-03-29 03:00:00"
```

The one thing that we can rely on is not the actual value of  `as.POSIXct(test)`, but that it will be different from `test` when `test` is an invalid date/time:

```
(as.character(test) == as.character(as.POSIXct(test))) %in% TRUE
# TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

I'm not sure that `as.character` is strictly necessary here, but I include it just to ensure that we don't fall foul of any other odd behaviours of POSIX objects.

Comment: I think you copied the output from `test` twice instead of pasting the output from `as.POSIXct(test)`, also the last check gives me `# TRUE NA TRUE`. But `(as.character(test) == as.character(as.POSIXct(test))) %in% TRUE` works for me.  
Not a beautiful solution but it works. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @snaut, good catch. I did paste the correct output, but the behaviour of `as.POSIXct` is clearly platform dependent. I've updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The manual says that `strptime` does not validate whether times exist in specific time zone because of the transition to/from daylight savings (`?strptime`). Also the manual says that `as.POSIXct` does this validation, so following the manual, one should check the resulting POSIXct object for NA (`?asPOSIXct`), which would identify non-existent time as shown in the question example. The result is however OS-specific for times that exist twice in a time zone (`?asPOSIXct`):

> Remember that in most time zones some times do not occur and some occur twice because of transitions to/from ‘daylight saving’ (also known as ‘summer’) time.  `strptime` does not validate such times (it does not assume a specific time zone), but conversion by `as.POSIXct` will do so.

and

> One issue is what happens at transitions to and from DST, for example in the UK
>
> `as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 01:30:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))`
> `as.POSIXct(strptime("2010-10-31 01:30:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))`
>
> are respectively invalid (the clocks went forward at 1:00 GMT to 2:00 BST) and ambiguous (the clocks went back at 2:00 BST to 1:00 GMT).  What happens in such cases is OS-specific: one should expect the first to be ‘NA’, but the second could be interpreted as either BST or GMT (and common OSes give both possible values).

Comment: Also, there is rarely a reason to use `POSIXlt`. POSIXct is usually preferable.

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer my question but rather states the problem again. I need to reliably detect non existant dates in a series of dates parsed from a csv and i need to distinguish them from other NA values that stem from empty strings, etc. Parsing directly to POSIXct is not possible, at least not with the standard libraries.